# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in Internet Explorer only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, foreach, warnings

Why is this warning occuring when I am using IE?

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

It works in all other browsers..

The function for the loop:

```
function wdsearch(PDO $dbh){
    if(!isset($_POST['wdsubmit'])) {
    } else {
        $term = $_POST['wdsearchvalue'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT      *
            FROM        posts
            WHERE       category = :designer
            AND         (full_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%')
            OR          heading LIKE CONCAT('%', :term, '%'))
            ORDER BY    post_date DESC
        ");
        $designer = 'Designer';
        $stmt->bindParam(":designer", $designer);
        $stmt->bindParam(":term", $term);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
wdsearch($dbh);
$wdsearch = wdsearch($dbh);
```

And the loop goes here..

```
<?php foreach($wdsearch as $wds) : ?>
<!-- HTML here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any possible IE related warnings? Like I said all other browsers can handle it..

Comment: It's not the browser. PHP errors are not browser-specific. `var_dump($wdsearch)`  before entering the loop and verify that it's an array or object.

Comment: Try some debugging. What's the difference of the input/values at various stages in your app?

Comment: There's no foreach statement in the code you pasted, so it's impossible to tell you what the issue might be.

Comment: $wdsearch is not defined or is not an array. It should be there for all browsers, but some styles may overlay the error with other content.

Comment: @DavidFells yes there is. It's the image (for some god-awful reason).

Comment: It cannot depend on your browser. This warning occurs when was passed not array to foreach.

Comment: @DavidFells I edited the original post to make it more readable.

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified error is occurring in your PHP code, not in any specific browser.

The issue is, the datatype of `$wdsearch`, does not implement an [`iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php). This could be caused by `$wdsearch` being `null`, a string/number/etc. - or simply an unsupporting object.

Try verifying if the data is an array before going into the `foreach` loop with `is_array($wdsearch)`, or verify the variable is not null with `isset($wdsearch)`. If you believe there is valid data there, check to see if the object in `$wdsearch` actually supports iterators and, if not, update it to implement!

Example:

```
<?php
if (isset($wdsearch)):
    foreach($wdsearch as $wds) :
        ?>
        <!-- HTML here -->
        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Tried var_dump($wdsearch) and resulted to be NULL

Comment: @Nworks The error is occurring in PHP, which has a server-side execution; this means that the browser doesn't matter. Is it possible you forgot to put the query-string on the URL in IE, but remembered it in the others?

Comment: @Nworks `null` is the killer! I've updated my answer to include a check using `isset()`; that should prevent the error - but you may want to add a "no data" message, or something similar.

Comment: I fixed it! Just had to change  if(!isset($_POST['wdsubmit'])) {    into > $_POST['wdsearchvalue']

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `wdsearch` function; if `$_POST['wdsubmit']` is not set, it returns nothing and if anything goes wrong in any of the db operations it will not return an array either.

You need to add some error handling to your db operations and in case of failure or a non-post, return an empty array **and** / **or** check if `$wdsearch` is an array before you use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If for the same parameters it works in Chrome and FF, but not IE.

What are exactly are you submitting in IE. Is there some silly thing like a button with picture submit? That would pass your terms as the location of the click, not actual value for example.

Debug what your incoming parameters in $POST are before outputting to foreach. Also how do you handle null result sets?